# splitting string from one column and extracting one part of string to another column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use sql server 2008 r2.
The problem started when one person entered data into the datebase in two different formats.

The table is: ( as u can notice there are `FName` and `LName` in column 'Title' but it should be in `FName` and `LName` columns respectively.

```
 Title                      FirstName         LastName
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
 Prasident Ena Enic          null              null    *(not ok)*
 Prasident                   Hana              Hanic   *(ok)*
 Prasident Jack Johnson      null              null    *(wrong)*
```

So  I splitted string in Title into 3 parts (`Title`, `SFirstName` and `SLastName`) using the code below.

```
ltrim(SUBSTRING (title ,CHARINDEX(' ', title)+1,
charindex(' ',title+' ',charindex(' ',title)+1)-charindex(' ',title)-1)),
ltrim(substring(title, charindex(' ',title,charindex(' ',title)+1), len(title)))
```

and I got this type od table.

```
SplittedTitle   SplittedFirstName  SplittedLastName  FirstName    LastName  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Prasident        Ena                 Enic              null         null
Prasident        Prasident           Prasident         Hana         Hanic
Prasident        Jack                Johnson           null         null
```

Now I have problem with nulls in `FirstName` and `LastName`. How can I transfer right data ( from SplittedFirstName and SplittedLastName) instead of nulls. I hope anyone got the point what my problem is.

Anyone have any idea?
Which function should I use and how?

Comment: please post the attempt you made with the code and the result you got

Comment: Is there any title value with more than one first name/last name? Like Prasident Jack Joe Tulsa Johnson? In that case how shall that be splitted?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an update.  You can do this with an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      <your query here>
     )
update toupdate
    set FirstName = SplittedFirstName,
        LastName = SplittedLastName
    where FirstName is null and LastName is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
x+IsNull(y,'')
```

which replaces y with empty string if it is null?

You can find more about this function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms184325.aspx):

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do now is,to run a update on that resultant table

```
UPDATE tablename  
SET   
FirstName = case when SplittedTitle <> SplittedFirstName  
                 then SplittedFirstName end,  
LastName = case when SplittedTitle <> SplittedLastName  
                then SplittedLastName end
```